# What causes a "Cannot register a null resource" error in ICEfaces?

Tags: download, nullpointerexception, icefaces

Java EE 5, JSF 1.2 with Facelets, ICEfaces 1.8.2

What can cause a "Cannot register a null resource" error in ICEfaces, using an ice:outputResource tag? From the ICEfaces source code, it looks like it's when the resource is null (duh), but I'm positive that it isn't. Are there any other possible causes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I got it. The Resource was an anonymous class, and one of the inherited methods I implemented in it (specifically, com.icesoft.faces.context.Resource.calculateDigest()) sometimes caused a NullPointerException that was nowhere to be seen in the stack trace.

I'm often frustrated with Java technologies' error messages; my productivity could probably be increased by 25% by having detailed, helpful error messages (it's a feature!).